# Parse - get parent items with their child items in array one to many relation

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, one-to-many, relation

I have the following relation in my Parse schema:
"Post" items with "Comments" child items. I'm Using Arrays for One-to-Many Relations as described here: [relations_guide](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide)

How can i fetch all Posts (even those with no comments) with all the comments for each post?

I was trying something like this:

```
var post = Parse.Object.extend("post");
var comment = Parse.Object.extend("comment");

var queryPosts = new Parse.Query(post);
var queryComments = new Parse.Query(comment);

queryPosts.matchesQuery("commentsList", queryComments);

return queryPosts.find().then(function (postsResult) {

console.log('prepareResponses: number of posts found: ' + postsResult.length);
```

and then, of course, I would like to get the comments out of the post
like this maybe?

```
p = postsResult[0].get("commentsList");
console.log("Number of comments in the first post is: " + p.length);
```

Comment: Are you trying to find all posts, all posts with certain comments, or all comments? It's unclear what you want

Comment: Trying to find all posts even those with zero comments) with all the comments for each post.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to query for all rows in a particular class (assuming comments is a relations object in post):

```
var post = Parse.Object.extend("post");
var postQuery = Parse.Query(post);
postQuery.includeKey("comments");
//post query will return all rows in post class with the comments relation loaded
```